# All cells in autofill range being set to nothing Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to use the autofill method in vba right now over a range that is set to a variable. I know that the range of cells you are autofilling *from* must be included in the destination. So, I do just that. However, and much to my surprise, all the cells in the range are being set to nothing.

Here is the code:

```
          Dim table2Range As Range
          Dim table2Range2 As Range
          Dim table2Range3 As Range
          Dim tableholder As Range


          Set table2Range2 = Range("Y54").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)   
          Set table2Range3 = Range("Y77").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
          Set table2Range = Range(table2Range2, table2Range3)
          Set tableholder = Range("y54", table2Range3)
          tableholder.Select

             table2Range.AutoFill Destination:=Selection    'This is setting all my cells to nothing for some reason
```

Here is the before & after screenshots:[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF9yq.png), [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9o75.png)

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why would using autofill helps is my question

Comment: That first screenshot actually didn't show what I wanted it to. The column with no header (the other columns have Q'#, for example) should be blank, I accidentally autofilled it manually. So, I want to autofill that would-be blank column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AutoFill line of code should be:

```
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:FillRange
```

It seems like your "table2Range " is the source, which overlap with your Fill Range. I.e:
 .End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) will set range from Y54 to the rightmost cell of the same row.

You can edit the source range with hardcode first (i.e. Range("Y54:Z77") and see if that works for you, then work from there

For example (try on a new workbook):

```
Sub example()
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B1")
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G1")
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
End Sub
```

Enter "1" in cell(A1) and "2" in Cell(B1) and run the code.

Comment: Right, but I was told that my Destination:FillRange needs to include the source range

Comment: Yes, say if you want to Autofill from Range A1:C1 to includes D1, your Destination will be A1:D1, while your **source range** should be A1:C1 (not A1:D1).  I've included an example on the answer - see if you can understand.

Comment: Ok yes, this is my issue. However, how would I do it  like this: Range("A1:A10").autofill(Range("A1:A10","C1:C10")?

Comment: @Matthew you mean like Range("A1:A10").autofill Destination:=Range("A1:A10","C1:C10")